# Yii2: How to save form data in two tables from one form?

Tags: mysql, yii2

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new CreateClient1();
        $employee = new Employee();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $employee->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
            $model->save();

            /*add same field in employee table*/

            $employee->client_code = $model->client_code;
            $employee->company_name = $model->company_name;
            $employee->emp_first_name = $model->emp_first_name;
            $employee->emp_last_name = $model->emp_last_name;
            $employee->emp_email = $model->emp_email;
            $employee->emp_mobile = $model->emp_mobile;
            $employee->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'employee' => $employee,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

My form looks like this do i need to add something in it?

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\CreateClient1 */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="create-client1-form">

   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>

    <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'client_code', ['value' => rand(1,100000000000000)]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'emp_email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'emp_mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'emp_first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'emp_last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>




</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Trying to insert same data in two tables.
Table CreateClient1 and Employee has to be same data, how do I insert in to Employee table in Yii2.
Any thing needs to add in form? my form form is not submitting

Comment: show _form.php, how u pass the data to controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new CreateClient1();
        $employee = new Employee();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
            $model->save();

            /*add same field in employee table*/
            $employee->attributes = $model->attributes;
            $employee->save();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'employee' => $employee,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updated. Check the if condition and try again

Comment: Are the model and employee fields exactly same?

Comment: Its getting value now, worked like charm thanks a lot

Comment: You can accept the answer if problem is solved. Glad I could help you:)

Comment: i have one more question how can i get you another than stackoverflow?

Comment: this is not an optimal answer as it does not care if the `CreateClient1` was actually added or not, but will continue attempting to add to the `Employee` table , at the least you should use the `if($model->save())` or better to use `Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction()` to wrap the code inside the transaction `try{}catch(){}` block so that in case of any database exception the transaction is rolled back

Comment: Yes @MuhammadOmerAslam you are right. I hope OP has taken care of that. I just showed him how it can be done.